# HTML code generated in mvc asp3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, formatting, code-generation

I have a small problem with asp mvc3
When i use PartialView in Razor Syntax

```
<ul class="nav-p navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Cart</a>
    </li>
    @Html.Partial("_AuthentPartial")
</ul>
```

and here is _AuthentPartial.cshtml

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{   
    <li class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello
                    <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("LogOff", "LogOff", "Account")
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
}

else
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("LogOn", "LogOn", "Account")
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")
    </li>
}
```

everything is ok, but when i view source HTML generated, code is not format, not alignment and very messy as you see below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9594I.png

What should i do to improve my code format ?